Can I use Cat 6A to create a USB B 3.0 Superspeed?
I'm trying to put my PC 10 meters away from me, and USB 3.0 active extenders have failed me due to interference with my 2 HDMI Cat 6A cables that shared the skirting board with it. I'm trying to find a cable that can help me, but they're all either cheap, thin unshielded USB 2.0 extenders, expensive 3.0 only extenders or very expensive fiber extenders. I don't wanna pay 60 € for a 10 m cable run, and I didn't think my requirements were that high, but I just cannot find any ethernet USB extenders.
Would it be possible for me to buy a USB type B/A 3.0 SS keystone and socket and create my own extender via Cat 6A Ethernet cable? The HDMI cables I have run 4k@144 Hz at this distance fine, and they don't seem to suffer from interference either.

USB 3.0 uses a spread-spectrum clock varying by up to 5000 ppm at 33 kHz to reduce EMI.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#Data_transfer_and_synchronization


CAT6A maximum frequency is 600 MHz under 100m


https://cablesys.com/updates/cat6-cat6e-cat6a-differences/


USB B 3.0 SS has 9 pins 


https://www.etechnophiles.com/usb-pinout-ports-connectors/

So if a Cat 6A cable has 4 twisted pairs + 1 ground wire, does that mean I can connect the 9 pins of the USB connector to the ethernet cable, and have it work over 10 m? The ground wire I could see as being a problem since it's not shielded, but I assume if that experienced interference the cable wouldn't just die. Not sure why there are two grounds, but maybe worst case I could just connect them to the same wire?
I have a 16 port active USB hub at the desk I expect it to connect to, which also runs at 3.0 speeds. It uses this USB B connector, with what I assume to be some sort of capacitor on the cable. Not sure if that is ommitable.
Do you think this has a chance of working and I should make it to test it out, or did I not notice a detail this would break on?
Thanks for the tips :)
edit1: why my 3.0 extender failed: https://linustechtips.com/topic/1575414-active-10m-usb-3-repeater-active-16-port-usb-hub-combo-not-working/#comment-16456600

No. But I'd love to see all the reasons why in the answers, and you may learn why the extenders are expensive! However, why do you think it's because of the interference? And what makes you think there is a capacitor on the cable? That would be really weird.

@pipe Check the edited question, that forum post of mine shows how me n other people concluded why it was interference. And as for the cap, idk I just assumed so. Googled, and it's ferrite bead used as an anti-EMI and anti-RFI measure (chokes).

In a simple word no, you are expecting too much and need an active USB extension cable without spending any more thought on custom solutions for extending 5 Gbps USB3 and USB2 for 10 meters.
Technically USB3 imposes no cable length limit, but rather performance limit so better cables can be longer than poor cables. Passive cables are expected to work for about 3 meters.
CAT6A performance is rated up to 500 MHz. Gigabit Etherned uses four lanes at 250 Mbps to reach 1 Gbps link.
USB3 at minimum uses single 5 Gbps transmit and single 5 Gbps return pair. You can't fit that for 10 meters through CAT6a without out-of-spec attenuation.
Besides the USB2 cable length limit is 5 meters due to not signal attenuation, but from the time how long it take the signal to travel through the cable, as USB2 HS is a half-duplex bus so a response is expected within a certain time.
So any cable extending USB2 for any more than 5 meters must officially be an active cable, somehow repeating packets so that longer delays than 5m cable is possible.
Also your HDMI cable might be active or optical. I would not expect cables longer than 5m pass the official HDMI 2.1 certification for signal attenuation at 12 Gbps per lane. Or, it's unvertified but just good enough for passing whatever signal you need for 10 meters.
If you can get a 10 meter USB3+USB2 extender for measly 60 euros, that is extremely cheap for such an extender, I expected real products to be much more expensive. You should get one, unless it's a fake product sold on shady online marketplaces that does not really work officially.

Thanks for your explanation. It makes me very sad that that's the case. I might still test it though, why not. Do you think Cat 7 or 8 would work then? cat 8: 2GHz max, 25 Gbps or 40 Gbps. I can find them between 10-30€ for 10m still.
https://www.alza.sk/premiumcord-usb3-2-2-0-predlzovaci-opticky-aoc-kabel-a-male-a-female-10-m-d8592572.htm this is the 60€ one I'm eyeballing. If you think it's fake, lemme know, but that brand is trusted in Czechoslovakia.

@djkato: You should read Justme's entire answer.  It clearly explains (in a self-contained way) why you cannot have a 10m passive cable supporting USB2, let alone both USB2 and USB3.

For starters, Cat 5/6 is 100 Ω characteristic impedance and USB is 90 Ω so you need to use active or passive means to bridge between them. At USB 3 speeds, this needs to be active. You’re not out 60 € in BOM cost immediately here, but with connectors and casing, close to it.

As I recall, the 90 Ω specification for USB is ±10%, so 100 Ω may well still work. I'm not sure if USB 3 requires tighter impedance tolerance, but I'd be surprised if the impedance difference alone would cause problems for USB 2 high speed, at least.
